# variable logging to file does not seem to work but has no exceptions

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, error-logging

I am trying to print out a multi lvl array so I can see what info is passed and maybe add something. 
I tried with a foreach but there are too many different levels depending on the request. 
There is also html text which hinders me reading the output with simple print_r
I copied a usually working exception log logging part and edited it. For some reason it is not working.
I also created the file in which to write and the folder exists.
I dont find any error logs indicating that there is an error
The script is continuing to execute after this part
I also tried this with the "error_log" func but I dont find that file either. 
Here I checked under ./var/log/ and not as with the dump under source/log/
I also checked the other load balancing servers...

**Code:**

```
    $sOfferId = $aArticle['ggebayofferid'];

    $aBody = $this->createOfferItem($aArticle);
    print_r("\n abody: ".$aBody." \n");  //<- this shows me that the execution is reaching here
    $sDump = "\n";
    $sDump .= $aBody;
    file_put_contents( "log/ebayupdate.log", $sDump, FILE_APPEND );  //<-- not able to find this log
    $sURL = $this->_sURL.'/sell/inventory/v1/offer/'.$sOfferId;
    //error_log( print_r($aBody, TRUE) );  <-- not able to find this log
```

Comment: 1. try using an absolute path; 2. check the return value of `file_put_contents`

Comment: You try put array in file not good idea
try
`echo '<pre>';
var_dump($aBody);
echo '<pre>';`

Comment: 1. $path = $this->_sShopBasePath."/log/ebayupdate.log";   this works, it is writing to the file only the word array of course... -.- but then  2. I get a return value

Comment: @AramMnatsakanyan this was the output I was looking for, thanks ^^

Comment: @AramMnatsakanyan but the html content is messing with the display

Comment: if you dump in browser your html code must show like a html content you can try run that script in cmd for view html code

Comment: or right click, inspect code and copy paste to notepad